# artsd on a server

Tags: audio, debian, daemon

On a debian server, I see artsd is running, I don't understand why. It's not my fault.

Is there some explication / usage to run a sound daemon on a server ?

```
~/ ps xf    
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 8300 ?        S      0:00 sshd: web@pts/1  
 8301 pts/1    Rs     0:00  \_ -zsh
 8691 pts/1    R+     0:00      \_ ps xf
25415 ?        S     18:43 /usr/bin/artsd -F 10 -S 4096 -s 60 -m artsmessage -l 3 -f
~/
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has a pretty informative [article about arts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARts).

I'd pull up aptitude, find arts (I'd expect it under Installed Packages / Sound / main), and see if any installed packages depend on it.  If there aren't any, it should be safe to remove.

Answer (score 0):

Could have something to do with VoIP.

Comment: I don't use VoIP. How can I see if my server use it ? Thanks for your help.